# Is there a Java alternative to Prefuse that is under active development?

Tags: java, visualization, prefuse

The [Prefuse](http://prefuse.org/) toolkit haven't been updated since 2009 and the last build is from 2007.  Is there any other Java visualization packages as powerful as Prefuse but has active community support/development?

Comment: Are there any particular visualization types or features that you are looking for...?

Comment: Prefuse is now open for development

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Protovis](http://vis.stanford.edu/protovis/) is the successor of Prefuse (and now, [D3](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/) is under active development). [Protovis-Java](http://vis.stanford.edu/protovis/protovis-java/) is a partial implementation of the Protovis toolkit in Java. There's a nice [example gallery](http://vis.stanford.edu/protovis/ex/), but I have no experience with the Java side.

As an alternative, you might consider [Processing](http://processing.org/), with some example of use in Java [here](http://www.cs.mun.ca/~hoeber/teaching/cs4767/notes/04-processing/), or its Javascript counterpart, [Processing.js](http://processingjs.org/). There were even a port for Scala + Processing: [Spde](http://technically.us/spde/About).

Comment: Unfortunately, SPDE is **not** under active development -- last commit  2 years ago